# How do I toggle the selection mode

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

Below is my code. When I click the icon with the class `cssDelUser` the  function below is called and I want the checkbox selection mode for the item with the id of `grid` to toggle between `checkbox` and `none`.

```
$(".cssDelUser").click(function() {
    $("#grid").jqxGrid({ selectionmode: smode });
    if (smode == 'checkbox') {
        smode = '';
    }
    else {
        smode = 'checkbox';
    }
});
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've changed how you get and set the selection mode.  Before, you were just changing the `smode` variable, not the actual value for the grid.

```
$(".cssDelUser").click(function() {
    var smode = $('#grid').jqxGrid('selectionmode');
    if (smode == 'checkbox') {
        $("#grid").jqxGrid({ selectionmode: 'none'});
    }
    else {
        $("#grid").jqxGrid({ selectionmode: 'checkbox'});
    }
});
```